# How to run Python commands on a socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I'd like to run some python code on a socket, i.e. listing the files in a directory on the socket. This is the code I have so far:

```
import socket, os
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 10000))
hi = os.listdir('/etc')
print(hi)`
```

In short, I'd like to run `os.listdir` on the `/etc` directory on the socket.
Help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: What does "on the socket" mean here? On the server-side of the socket?

Comment: There are many options, but the big thing is that the client (your side since you connected) and the server (the thing you connected to) need to agree on what you are doing. If the server just wants a list of files in your current drectory, `clientsocket.send(hi.encode('utf-8'))` followed by `clientsocket.close()` may be reasonable. Consider that existing protocols like `ftp` and `telnet` can be leveraged for this task.

Comment: I don't have access to the server side of the socket- however, I can send and receive data from it. I'd just like to send a command to list the files in the /etc directory